# Why can't I move in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why can't i move  when I join any server? All the buttons are gone, and all I can do is break blocks. It doesn't even show the item hotbar!

Comment: Have you tried to re-install?

Comment: Check that 'hide gui' isn't turned on

Answer (score 1):

You might have "Hide GUI" on, and if you do, turn it off and that should give you your hotbar back.

To move, you might need to set up an account in the chat window. After that, you should be able to move.

Answer (score 0):

Many server block players movement to force them to subscribe to server by a command, watch out what the server tells you when you just connect to it.